# Certificate SSL in local. Java - Tomcat

Tags: java

I need to create a local certificate for ssl to work.

I do the next three steps and everything goes correctly

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/bin/keytool -export -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt

sudo /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file tomcat.crt -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

The problem that when creating the certificate I messed up the data and I want to do it again.

But I do not know how to erase everything.

I deleted the tomcat.crt file from my home

And I have executed:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/bin/keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

But when I run again:

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7u80/jre/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

I get the following error

```
 Key tool error: java.lang.Exception: The key pair has not been generated, the alias <tomcat> already exists
```

And I do not know where else I have to remove things, to be able to regenerate the certificate from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

[genKey also takes a keystore argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)

```
-genkeypair {-alias alias} {-keyalg keyalg} {-keysize keysize} {-sigalg sigalg} [-dname dname] [-keypass keypass] {-validity valDays} {-storetype storetype} {-keystore keystore} [-storepass storepass] {-providerClass provider_class_name {-providerArg provider_arg}} {-v} {-protected} {-Jjavaoption}
```

So, I assume what might be happening here is that genkey creates the key pair in a keystore that is not the one you pass with `-keystore` to the other commands.

Try `-delete` without the `-keystore` option to get to the same keystore your `-genkey` created the keys in.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The command could be shorter if option defaults are accepted or
>   you wish to be prompted for various values. Whenever you execute a
>   keytool command, defaults are used for unspecified options that have
>   default values, and you are prompted for any required values. For the
>   genkey command, options with default values include alias (whose
>   default is mykey), validity (90 days), and keystore (the file named
>   .keystore in your home directory). Required values include dname,
>   storepass, and keypass.

As mentioned in [Oracle Official Tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html) at the bottom.

So, while creating the key, your keystore is `~/.keystore` however while deleting the alias you are deleting it from `cacerts`.

After doing that when you are trying to create a new key, you are not specifying any keystore hence the default `~/.keystore` is referred where the key with alias already exists as you never deleted it from there!

I hope this helps and would recommend reading more about keytool usage